# Unable to connect to RabbitMQ on server

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have the below code that connects to RabbitMQ on my local machine but when I change Host name from localhost to my servername it fails and returns the error

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.UserName = "myuser";
factory.Password = "mypassword";
factory.VirtualHost = "/";
factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
factory.HostName = "localhost";
```

As soon as I change HostName as below, it returns error

```
factory.HostName = "myserver";
```

> Exception: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
>
> The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by
>   Library, code=0, text=\"End of stream\", classId=0, methodId=0,
>   cause=System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Peer missed 2 heartbeats with
>   heartbeat timeout set to 60 seconds

Comment: Can you ping the server? Is the RabbitMQ server running on that server? Can you connect to the RabbitMQ port using (e.g.) telnet? Did you punch a hole in the firewall? Is there anything in the RabbitMQ logs on the server?

Comment: I'm able to ping and remote login to the server; how do i check RabbigMQ logs? I'm pretty much starter on this; thanks

Comment: I got to see the logs by Admin and noticed that VirtualHost is /filestream insetad of /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server, it looks like Host Name is configured different.  My Admin looked at logs and looked at configuration and provided me with the Host Name on server.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.UserName = "myuser";
factory.Password = "mypassword";
factory.VirtualHost = "/filestream";
factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
factory.HostName = "myserver";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of connecting this way, it's much easier to connect using a connection string like you would with sql.

**Example C#**:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    Uri = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RabbitMQ"].ConnectionString,
    RequestedHeartbeat = 15,
    //every N seconds the server will send a heartbeat.  If the connection does not receive a heartbeat within
    //N*2 then the connection is considered dead.
    //suggested from http://public.hudl.com/bits/archives/2013/11/11/c-rabbitmq-happy-servers/
    AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true
};
return factory.CreateConnection();
```

**web.config or app.config**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RabbitMQ" connectionString="amqp://{username}:{password}@{servername}/{vhost}" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I don't know this; thanks for letting us know;  very useful